# Coherence result for (braided) monoidal functors

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Is there any coherence result for (braided) monoidal functors? (like Mac Lane's coherence theorem for monoidal categories)

What I have in mind is a theorem like the following:

> Let $F$ be a (braided) monoidal functor between monoidal categories $\mathsf C$ and $\mathsf D$. All compositions in the category $D$, with the same source and target, consisting of the structure maps $\alpha$, $\rho$,
>   $\lambda$, $F(\alpha)$, $F(\rho)$, $F(\lambda)$, ($\sigma$, $F(\sigma)$) are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Have a look at:

> Lewis, G. (1972) *Coherence for a closed functor*. In: Mac Lane, S. (ed.) *Coherence in Categories*. Springer-Verlag Lecture Notes in Computer Science 281, 148–195
>
> Epstein, D. B. A. (1966) *Functors between tensored categories*. Invent. Math. 1, 221–228

Comment: These papers were published before braided categories were introduced (AFAIK, it was Joyal and Street around 1986). Do you know of any reference specifically for braided functors? Joyal and Street's 1993 paper does not have such a theorem in it.

Comment: I'd be interested in a corresponding strictification result for symmetric monoidal functors...

Answer (score 1):

Nick Gurski and I have some results about this in a new preprint! [Universal pseudomorphisms, with applications..](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.11261). It's a little more subtle than the "*all formal diagrams commute*" version you had in mind, but only because of details in the coherence for braided (or symmetric) monoidal categories.  (Or, maybe this *is* the version you had in mind, and I misunderstood.  Anyway, details below.)

### Summary

In a braided monoidal category $D$, the condition for a formal diagram to commute is that the *underlying braid* for each composite around the diagram must be the same. If $D$ is symmetric monoidal, then the condition for the diagram to commute is that the *underlying permutations* for each composite must be the same. For references: the first of these is [Joyal-Street](https://dx.doi.org/10.1006/aima.1993.1055) Corollary 2.6, and the second is in [Mac Lane's book](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-4721-8) Section XI.1.
We also have a review of them in section 11 of our preprint.

Or Theorem 1.6 says that coherence for a braided or symmetric *strong* monoidal functor $f: C \to D$ is *no more complicated* than coherence in the target, $D$. In particular, the monoidal and unit constraints for $f$ do not introduce any additional complication. The details involve

1. a precise definition of "formal diagram" for $f$, and
2. a process we call "dissolution" that simplifies a formal diagram.

For (1), the definition of "formal diagram" for $f$ is basically any diagram that involves only monoidal/unit constraints of $f$ along with monoidal/braiding data of $C$ and $D$. This is made precise by a certain universal construction that is "freely generated" by the data of a braided/symmetric monoidal functor. (Actually, we do this more generally for pseudomorphisms over a 2-monad $T$, but one can read the whole paper just assuming that $T$ is the 2-monad for braided or symmetric monoidal categories.)

For (2), "dissolution" basically means replacing all of the monoidal and unit constraints of $f$ with *identities*. This is a drastic change, and requires also changing some of the objects. Making it precise depends on the details of "formal diagram" above, and a (2-)functor called $\Delta$. Our Theorem 1.3 is that $\Delta$ is an *equivalence* for a wide class of 2-monads $T$, including the 2-monads for plain, braided, and symmetric monoidal structures.

So, the slogan version of our main application (Theorem 1.6) is the following.

**If $H$ is a formal diagram for $f$, and if the dissolution diagram $|H|$ commutes, then the original diagram $H$ also commutes.**

The dissolution diagram $|H|$ is always a formal diagram in the target category, $D$, so determining commutativity of $|H|$ depends on the coherence for braided/symmetric monoidal categories (or, whatever other $T$-algebras one might consider). That's what I mean by saying that coherence for $f$ is no more complicated than coherence in the target, $D$. And, because $\Delta$ sends the monoidal and unit constraints of $f$ to identities, they *do not contribute* to the dissolution diagram $|H|$ at all. That's what I mean by saying that $|H|$ is a simplification of the original diagram $H$.

### Examples

We spent some time putting several examples in sections 15 and 16 of the paper, so please take a look there if you're interested in more of the details!  We tried to write them without assuming that people have already read the first 14 sections, and I would be interested to hear how well that worked out. I also wrote a mathstodon thread with a [more leisurely overview](https://mathstodon.xyz/@nilesjohnson/111607399597070286) including pictures and examples.

I'm happy to answer more questions either here or there, since we're pretty excited about how this came out!

### Further notes

**Note 1**: The assumption that $f$ is strong monoidal means that its monoidal and unit constraints ($f_2$ and $f_0$) are isomorphisms. The work of [Lewis](https://dx.doi.org/10.26190/unsworks/8943) shows that coherence for *lax* monoidal functors is very different from the strong monoidal case, and our proofs depend crucially on the assumption that f is strong monoidal.

**Note 2**: There is also a version of our results when $T$ is the 2-monad for plain monoidal categories. In that case, every formal diagram in D does commute (that's Mac Lane's theorem; there are no underlying permutations or braids to check). So, our result implies that *every* formal diagram for a strong monoidal functor $f$ will commute. That conclusion is similar to the theorem of [Epstein](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01452242), but there are two key differences:

- Our result only applies to strong monoidal functors.
- Epstein's tensored categories are *non unital*, so his result applies to diagrams for a lax monoidal functor that *do not involve the unit*.
  This second point is explained a bit more by [Lewis](https://dx.doi.org/10.26190/unsworks/8943).

I don't know of any work that treats coherence for general braided or symmetric *lax* monoidal functors.

**Note 3**: I first came across this question while we were formulating the ideas for this paper, trying to decide whether the details of the braided/symmetric monoidal applications were worth spelling out carefully.  I was trying to figure out if coherence for those cases was already written somewhere else in the literature, and this question helped me decide they were not!  So, thanks :)

### References

Here are the titles that I was referencing above; they're also mentioned in the other answer here.

[Joyal-Street, Braided tensor categories, 1993.](https://dx.doi.org/10.1006/aima.1993.1055)

[Mac Lane, Categories for the working mathematician, 1998.](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-4721-8)

[Lewis, Coherence for a closed functor, 1974.](https://dx.doi.org/10.26190/unsworks/8943)

[Epstein, Functors between tensored categories, 1966.](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01452242)